# MySQL GROUP by or using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have an issue that seems to be quiet easy but I just would like to ask how you would solve it:

In a MySQL-table there is the following structure:

```
provider     artist      
a            1
a            2
a            3
b            4
```

Now it is necessary to echo a list in HTML like:

```
provider a
1
2
3

provider b
4
```

I stuck at the point where I would like to group the results and echo them out with `for-each` and `while` loop.

The main idea is quiet simple like:

```
<?php $query = mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP by provider");

foreach GROUP {?>

  echo some styling HTML-code for each group of headline;

  <?php while ($data= $query->fetch_assoc()){?>

  echo some styling HTML-code for each list-item;

<?php};?>
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for answering.

The solution fro RiggsFolly seems to work fine. There is just a small problem with the HTML. There is a surrounding div-tag that wont be closed when adding the HTML code in that line:

```
 echo 'provider '. $data->provider;
```

The problem is that the while loop needs to be in the div. The closing div-tag is missing for every

```
if ( $current_provider != $data->provider ) {
```

Here is the original HTML-code:

```
    <?php
        $service = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `system` ORDER BY provider, artist");
        $current_provider = NULL;

        while ($data = $service->fetch_object()) {
            if ( $current_provider != $data->provider ) {// new provider?>
    <div class="service">
    <p class="lower">
     <?php echo $data->provider;?>
    </p>
    <?php
        $current_provider = $data->provider;
    }?>
    <a href='?artist=<?php echo $data->artist;?>'><?php echo "/".$data->artist;?</a><br/>   
    <?php };?>
</div><!--service -->
```

The list-items will be shown nicely. But when looking into the Source code you can see that the closing div-tag is missing. Thanks

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem simpler to not use a `GROUP BY` especially as it will not provide you with the data that you want. So instead just select them all and sort them by provider and maybe artist as a sub sort like so

```
<?php 
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY provider, artist");

    $current_provider = NULL;

    while ($data = $result->fetch_object()){
        if ( $current_provider != $data->provider ) {
            // new provider
            echo 'provider '. $data->provider;
            $current_provider = $data->provider;
        }
        echo $data->artist;
    }
?>
```

AFTER UPDATE:

```
<?php
    $service = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `system` ORDER BY provider, artist");

    $current_provider = NULL;

    while ($data = $service->fetch_object()) {

        if ( $current_provider != $data->provider ) {
            if ( $current_provider !== NULL ) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '<div class="service">';
            echo '<p class="lower">' . $data->provider . '</p>';
            $current_provider = $data->provider;
        }
        echo '<a href="?artist=' . $data->artist '">' .
             $data->artist . '</a><br/>';   
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: good sir, this is also worked same as my answer and it's easy

Comment: @DipeshShihora Not quite the same, as you are using `GROUP BY` which wont list the artists.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping me out. there is still a problem with the html part in your code. to face the problem i updated my uestion. kind regards.

Comment: Strictly thats a new question, but give me a second to amend my answer

Comment: There yoo go, how is that!

Comment: Any reason why you removed the correct answer flag on this answer, was something wrong with the solution?

Comment: Hello, you did great work! But there is still an issue with the code that causes a unpretty "failure". I gave further information under UPDATE2. Maybe you could help me again to solve the issue because you do understand your code best :) Thanks alot.

Comment: **I think you are missing the primary goal of SO which is**. Someone asks a specific question, people answer that specific question. Answers get upvoted if they are good and TICKED if they solve the problem. This means **others** can search for this problem and look for the good answer/correct answers and that hopefully solves their problem too. You are **not supposed to change the question** once its asked and **especially not once its answered**. You cannot use a single question to get someone to develop your whole script for you. Ask another question once you change the requirement.

Comment: alright, I'm sorry. I often read "marked as possible duplicate..." so I  thought that it would be the best to open just one uestion. I will accept your answer again. Nevertheless thanks alot for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: More than willing to help again if I can. You had better remove the UPDATE2 from this question so as not to confuse others. I am not desperately bothered about the tick, although thank you, but I do use SO **often** as well as contribute to it so I appreciate the ethos and would like to keep it pure.

Comment: opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562616/mysql-order-by-and-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

How about that.

```
<?php $query = mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
    $current_group = array();
   while ($data= $query->fetch_assoc()){
      if(in_array($data['provider'],$current_group)){
         echo  "<h1>New Group" . $data['provider'] ."</h1>";
         $current_group[] = $data['provider']
      }
     echo $data['artist'] . "<br/>";
   }
```

Comment: Except that `GROUP BY` will not provide the individual `artists` so it is actually useless in this situation

Comment: And now you have removed the `GROUP BY` but not added an `ORDER BY` so you are likely to get some **duplicated providers** as they may be delivered in any order.